# I am trying to install ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) on HP 15 bs576tx but bluetooth and wifi is not showing up, anyone knows how to install the drivers?

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth, hp

I am trying to install ubuntu on HP 15 bs576tx but bluetooth and wifi is not showing up, anyone knows how to install the drivers? I tried searching for the same which is available on https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/HP-bs576tx-wifi-card-not-detected-in-Ubuntu-16-04/m-p/6355584/highlight/true#M142283, but it is archived. Though I have the same file downloaded long back but somewhat confused, can someone please help? or may be any link to updated drivers?

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; and if you're talking about a LTS release, two kernel stack choices can be chosen - so please be specific.

Comment: For what it is worth, the drivers are no longer supported by HP, so it is a heck of a job to find something useful that would work for your setup, I can find no reference or anything. Question remains, like guiverc asked: what ubuntu release you are using? I found many complaints on the very same matter re: HP 15 bs576tx btw,,,,,,

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command along with the other information already requested.

Comment: @Rob Seldom the manufacturers publish specific Linux drivers for consumer grade hardware for which there isn't (and never was) official Linux support. That rarely is a problem because we can get drivers for the components/parts either already supported by the kernel or using proprietary drivers from other sources, hence the pertinence of the information guiverc asked about in the first comment.

Comment: Roger that, point taken ChanganAuto. I was referring to the windows side of things whereas once obtained they might help, but that is the wrong idea obviously. Where would hellokiddie 01 need to turn in order to obtain?